# Windows, Ruby on rails bundle installer issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

I've no idea what happened, but I've started getting this error:

```
c:\Sites\Project>ruby bin/rails server
Your bundle is locked to rake (12.0.0), but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. 
If you haven't changed sources, that means the author of rake (12.0.0) has removed it. 
You'll need to update your bundle to a different version of rake (12.0.0) that hasn't been removed in order to install.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I've been using railsinstaller 2.3, and after getting it switched over to 2.2, but it is not helping.
Running bundle install produces exact same error text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran

```
gem install rubygems-bundler
gem regenerate_binstubs
```

then

```
bundle install
```